# Breaklinks in PowerPoint running but not working

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am working on a PowerPoint including charts that links to data in Excel. I would like to remove this link through a macro in VBA. 
I use the following macro which executes without errors, but when I look through the PowerPoint I can still follow the links back to my Excel file. Is anyone able to see the problem?

```
Sub BreakAllLinks()

    Dim oSld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim oSh As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim Yes As Integer
    Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application

    Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    '// Check if more then single powerpoint open
    If PowerPointApp.Presentations.Count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please close all other PowerPoints"
        Exit Sub
    End If


Yes = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to break all links in your active PowerPoint presentation?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Break ALL links")

If Yes = vbYes Then
    For Each oSld In PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oSh In oSld.Shapes
            If oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then   'SOLUTION EDIT: msoChart
                oSh.LinkFormat.BreakLink
            End If
        Next   ' Shape
    Next   ' Slide
End If


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added the solution as a comment in the code. I am not sure what the convention is here. Should I just correct my code and leave out the comment or leave the wrong code with the solution embedded in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start by saying I'm not an expert in OLE linked charts. Someone else may explain this much better than myself. So disclaimer done ... oSh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject doesn't correctly identify all linked charts. A linked chart maybe oSh.Type = msoChart for example. I've found that a better way of identifying a chart that is linked is by testing for the existence of the property Shape.LinkedFormat.AutoUpdate ... the property AutoUpdate only exists for linked charts ... and does not exist for non-linked charts. Referring to it for a non-linked chart will generate a runtime error. However if we're going to use its existance, then check whether a property exists in VBA (a pretty clunky process). For example:

```
Private Function IsLinked(myShape As Shape)
    Dim AutoUpdate As Variant
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    IsLinked = False
    AutoUpdate = myShape.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate
    IsLinked = True
Err_Handler:

End Function
```

So you could test if oSh is linked using the above function. The next challenge is that BreakLink doesn't  (always) work. The best method is to simply set AutoUpdate to manual update ... like:

```
oSh.LinkFormat.AutoUpdate = ppUpdateOptionManual
```

Alternatively, you could always copy the charts in without the links in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. The solution, as you provided, was simply changing frin `msoLinkedOLEObject` to `msoChart`. So simple I am a bit ashamed that I didn't think of it myself!